# Is there any difference between "as before" and "as like before"?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage, ielts

Suppose, in an English language written exam, there is a question which asks to write a formal report comparing two maps (which are given in the question paper). (note: I have attached the maps here, please check).

Both the maps are for SAME island, showing past and present condition of the island.
While writing the report, in the first paragraph I have written about what things were on the island in the past. I have written -

> There were some trees on both sides of the island.

I also have written some other things in the first paragraph. In total 2-3 sentences in the first paragraph.

In the 2nd paragraph, I have written about all the things/improvements which can be seen from the present map of the island.

In the 2nd paragraph, I talked about the houses, pear [pier], swimming area, foothpath etc. After that I talked about trees like this -

> The trees on the right portion are still there as before.

By "as before", I meant "as/like in the previous (past) map" .

Someone told me that, "as before" is WRONG. The correct usage is "as like before". --

> The trees **on the right portion** are still there as **like** before.

I am not sure which one is correct?

[image]

Comment: [as before,like before,as like before](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like+before%2Cas+before%2Cas+like+before&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clike%20before%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20before%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20like%20before%3B%2Cc0) are all pretty much equal semantically, but the first is *much* more common, and in practice the last is almost never used. I think whoever told you that "as before" is WRONG doesn't know what they're talking about.

Comment: _As like before_ is overkill. _As_ means _like_; use one or the other, not both.

Comment: so both "as before" and "like before" are correct while writing Formal report in english language exam? Is there any difference between their usage in sentence?

Comment: I"d say "as before" is right, "like before" isn't exactly right but (unfortunately) rather common, and "as like before" is wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot everyone. Just want to know that - is your first language English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"As like before" is incorrect.

Comment: I tried to change the -1 to +1(useful) many times, but not working

Comment: Hahaha, no worries man.

Comment: This answer is downvoted because StackExchange answers should *explain*, not merely *tell*. *Why* is "as like before" incorrect? For example, you could compare the prevalence of the phrases in a large corpus, or compare the difference between *as* and *as like*. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help].